# .htaccess - hide folder and .html

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, directory

My folder structure looks like this: 
`domain.com/html/page.html` .

If I click on a link on the page I want the URL to look like this: `domain.com/page` .

I tried out different .htaccess snippets but nothing worked the way I want. At the moment you can visit `domain.com/html/page` and you see the right page, but if you click on a link the URL is `domain.com/html/page.html` .

My .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /$1.html [QSA,L]
```

I hope, someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect /html/some-page.html to /some-page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/html/([^/]+)\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite /some-page to /html/some-page.html if it exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/html/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ html/$1.html [L]
```